# Regex end in backslash

Tags: javascript, regex, html, validation

I'm using regex in javascript to validate a form.  One of the form fields is a filepath so needs to end in a backslash.

Specifically, I'm using `<input type="text" pattern="" />` and I want to fill out the Pattern attribute to validate it.

Now..

I understand you make a backslash literal by doubling up ie. \\

and I understand that you use the dollar ($) sign to find the end of the string.

So can anyone explain to me why $// and //$ don't work?  And maybe give me an example of something that would work?

Thanks

Comment: you should use \/ to escape the slash

Comment: You need the `$` _after_ the backslash. `\\$`. That is, a backslash followed by the end of the string. _"why $// and //$ don't work?"_ - Well you're using forward-slashes there, not backslashes. By the way, why do you assume a file path has to end in a backslash - some operating systems use forward slashes, and in any case can't you just assume a terminating backslash if it isn't supplied?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it working if I match the entire input, like so  `.*\\$`

Dropping the $ behaved ok too,

```
<form>
  path: <input type="text" pattern=".*\\" title="ends in \">
</form>
```

(using Chrome 27)

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be mixing up slash `/` with backslash `\`. A `\\$` is different from a `//$`, and `\\$` should work.